# Are c++ module files platform independent / cross platform?

Tags: c++, header, std, c++20, c++-modules

I have a large .cpp file that takes many minutes to compile, I want to share it with a friend, they have an arm machine, and I have an x86 machine. Can I make it a c++ module on my machine and email it to my friend so they can use the module without having to compile the large .cpp file? We are both running the same type of operating system and are using compilers from the same vendor if that matters.

Comment: No, not right away. You *could* install an ARM cross-compiler and use that to compiler the code. But if you use an x86 compiler, the files will not work on non-x86 systems.

Comment: I'm seeing some confusion here over compiled modules vs. the final binary form. A compiled module is meant to be a binary representation of the AST. The question is asking whether it's okay to share that, not the final binary.

Comment: *"same type of operating system"*, yet different architectures?

Answer (score 2):

None of this is specified by the standard, so it will be different for different compilers and platforms. But usually, the output products of a module compilation are object files (libraries, so definitely CPU-specific) and module files. The latter are at the very least *compiler* specific (and may even be sensitive to compiler *versions*) and can very well be CPU or OS specific (especially if you have any `#ifdef`s that are CPU-specific).

It would be much more portable to just hand them your source files and let them build the module one time themselves.

Answer (score -2):

Code written using modules should be portable across different platforms and compilers that support the C++20 standard. However, the key here is the support for C++20 modules by the specific compiler you and your friend are using.